# Trigger CiviRule based on contribution receive date with field value comparison relative to today

Tags: civirules, fieldvaluecomparison

I'm trying to trigger a CiviRule when a contribution is created with a receive date earlier than today, using field value comparison, but I don't seem to be able to get this to work. According to [this previous question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11895/can-civirules-be-triggered-off-a-custom-field-of-type-date-for-eg-date-equals-no), I should be able to use yesterday, -1 day and similar, but none of these options are working for me. Has anyone else been able to get something along these lines to work?

The field value comparison appears to be working:
[image]
[image]
but the rule is never triggered.

I'm seeing a warning logged, but it doesn't seem directly related:
[warning] Attributes passed to CRM_Core_Form::add() are not an array. Caller: CRM_CivirulesConditions_Form_ValueComparison::buildQuickForm
Array
(
[civi.tag] => deprecated
)

Comment: Looks like that warning has already been fixed, just not released yet:
https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civirules/-/commit/60b620a8e9f9460f1b58343d745e6bc6e8799c3c
In any case, the same warning is logged with a condition that does work, so it's not related.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is but you should be a able to debug the isConditionValid function in the generic form value comparison and that should tell you what the problem is?

Comment: Yes, looks like getComparisonValue is returning the date as a string in format 2022-09-15 here (https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civirules/-/blob/master/CRM/CivirulesConditions/Generic/ValueComparison.php#L93), but getFieldValue is returning a string in format 20220901162600. I'll open an issue on Gitlab.

Comment: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civirules/-/issues/186